# Rails: Bootstrap& SASS dependency management

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, dependency-management

My project has four style sheets:

```
universal_styles.sass
shared_styles.sass
articles.css.sass
options.css.sass
```

`articles.css.sass` and `options.css.sass` both contain:

```
@import 'universal_styles'; 
@import 'shared_styles'`;
```

However, both `universal_styles.sass` and `shared_styles.sass` styles both require `@import 'bootstrap'`.  I am trying to avoid importing Bootstrap twice.

One solution I had was to `@import 'universal_styles'` in `shared_styles.sass`, then `@import 'shared_styles'` in both articles and options.  However, this has a very static, inflexible feel.

In general I am trying to find a way to add sass files which:

1. Any imported file can have access to Bootstrap classes and variables
2. Bootstrap is only included once, at the start of the file containing @import directives.

I was looking for a sass directive which will only process sass after all the import directives are completed.

Another attempt was made to include the file using `<%= require 'shared_styles.sass' %>` in options and articles to directly include the file without SASS preprocessing.  However, this method would not compile.  Perhaps there is another way to do it?

If you know of a best practice, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't really know the specifics of your environment, however, this is not an ideal configuration for css. You want to limit the number of files that you're loading from a server. In this case, it looks like you're loading four stylesheets to the end user. I'd suggest making this one, even if the user is on a page that doesn't require all of the styles. Rather, use partials. Basically sass that doesn't compile on it's own. a sass partial is any file with an underscore in front of the name. i.e. (_input.scss) Here's my suggestion:

Master stylesheet:

```
//main.scss
@import "libs/libs";
@import "global/global";
@import "modules/modules";
```

Now let's look at each of these three files. keeping them in different folders is just how I do. If you'd like to see an alternate layout I can suggest something. anyways, let's continue the wiring with bootstrap in the libs folder:

```
//_libs.scss
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

Now for the global:

```
//_global.scss
@import "shared";
@import "universal";
```

Lastly, modules. which again, don't assume that you have to stick to this naming convention.

```
//_modules.scss
@import "articles";
@import "options";
```

I changed the structure of my scss recently (about a month ago) to something that was a little more flexible. Here's an overview of how it works. [Atomic Design Methodology](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/)